# Why won't Javascript code run?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new new to javascript. This is my first real attempt to do something besides running hello world. I'm attempting to retrieve information from a url and display it. I checked the url and it returns json. The "Hello World" code runs but as soon as I add the code that retrieves the json inside the script tags nothing happens. I'm getting no syntax errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<body>

  <p>Header...</p>

  <script>
    document.write("Hello World");

    var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("get", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        callback(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();

};

  getJSON("http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=US&date=2016-08-31",
  function(err, data) {
  if (err != null) {
    alert("Something went wrong: " + err);
  } else {
    alert("Your query count: " + data.query.count);
  }
});

  </script>
  <p>...Footer</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your html and js and one quick look into the console showed me that the problem was this line

```
alert("Your query count: " + data.query.count);
```

change the "data.query.count" to "data.length"

```
alert("Your query count: " + data.length);
```

Debuging code is one of the easiest ways to find errors.
You can hit F12 in basicly any browser to inspect the things behind the scene

[image]

Comment: I was using a js online editor that was contributing to my confusion.  After  viewing the answer, fixing the alert("Your query count: " + data.query.count) statement and running as HTML, was able to get results. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the console on your browser you will see that your code is throwing the error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined`.

This is because you are attempting to access the length of the response array by means of `data.query.count`, when in fact it should be `data.length`.

So the working code should look like;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<body>

  <p>Header...</p>

  <script>
    document.write("Hello World");

    var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("get", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
    callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
    callback(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();

};

  getJSON("http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=US&date=2016-08-31",
  function(err, data) {
  if (err != null) {
    alert("Something went wrong: " + err);
  } else {
    alert("Your query count: " + data.length);
  }
});

  </script>
  <p>...Footer</p>

</body>

</html>
```